# RPi compile under ubuntu

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc

I am trying to compile Raspbian inside of Ubuntu by downloading them through the Git repository, but the tools.git never gets completely downloaded.

I followed another article which insisted on adding another parameter, `depth=1`. By doing that I was able to complete the download with a lesser size; after which I was able to complete the configuration setup, compilation, and addition of modules.

But when I tried creating the kernel.img file, first the mkimage folder didn't exist, then I manually downloaded the files and then added to the tools folder after which I get following error:

```
dips@dips:~/raspbian/tools/mkimage$ sudo python ./imagetool-uncompressed.py ../../linux/arch/arm/boot/Image
[sudo] password for dips: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./imagetool-uncompressed.py", line 35, in <module>
    load_to_mem("boot-uncompressed.txt", 0x00000000)
  File "./imagetool-uncompressed.py", line 30, in load_to_mem
    mem[addr] = int(value >> i * 8 & 0xff)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment
```

I am following the steps mentioned [here](http://simonmcc.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/raspberry-pi-rpi-kernel-build-for.html)

Thanks .

Comment: Personally I'd follow the instruction at http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md or http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation . I used the eLinux instructions without problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person who wrote that blog is a bit of a twit.  You do not need anything other than the cross-compiler to build and install a kernel.  Ignore anything that involves the separate "tools" directory.

> i was able to complete the configuration setup and compilation

Good.  Go into the `arch/arm/boot` subdirectory.  There should be a file there 2-4 MB in size called `zImage`, presuming your configuration used gzip as the compression mode.  If not (you can check this in menuconfig, it's *General setup -> Kernel compression mode*), it may be called `bzImage` for bzip2; I'm not sure what it will be for the other modes.

Copy that onto the first (vfat) partition of the SD card.  Rename it, e.g., `test-kernel`. Now edit the `config.txt` file in that partition and comment out the current `kernel=` line and add a replacement:

```
#kernel=kernel.img
kernel=test-kernel
```

Now copy the modules and firmware over into the `/lib` directory on the second (ext4) partition.  First, I would back up the current firmware directory, since there's only one, and I have no idea how responsible Simon's choice of configuration was.  From inside the lib directory:

```
tar -cjf firmware.tb2 firmware
```

This should leave a `firmware.tb2` file behind.  You can leave it there or store it somewhere else.  If you need to restore things later you can use `tar -xjf firmware.tb2` from inside the same directory.

Simon says to erase the current firmware and modules directory.  **NO. NO. NO. DO NOT.**  Just use the two `cp -a` commands to copy stuff in.  This will overwrite as necessary and leave whatever isn't being replaced.

You can now try to boot.  If it doesn't work, you can edit `config.txt` again and comment out your new line and uncomment the old one to return to the original kernel.  In this case, if you want to try again, I would recommend starting with the config used for the original kernel, then add to that in menuconfig.  You need to get that from a *running* pi; it will be `/proc/config.gz`.<sup>1</sup>  It is not actually on the SD card so don't bother looking for it.  You can put that file in the top level of the kernel source and:

```
gunzip config.gz
mv config .config
```

This will replace the one that's there.  Now fire up `make menuconfig`, do whatever, and go through the build and install process again.

---

<sup>1.  If you can't find it, try `sudo modprobe configs` and look again.</sup>